# Magnetic pole in a wire

Tags: electromagnetism

When you pass a current through a wire you create magnetic fields around it. In this case where is the the North Pole and the South Pole?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess, any current will produce a magnetic field. DC current flows in one direction. I'd guess the positive direction of flow of current would be North Pole and the other end south, say if your electromagnet is wire wrapped around a nail. Reverse the current and your poles reverse. But what about AC current? That logic breaks down in that case. I'm thinking having non-permanent magnet having a pole might not make sense.

Comment: This other question relates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266854/is-the-south-pole-of-an-electromagnet-always-at-the-end-where-current-is-drawn-i

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic fields always form closed loops.  The end of a magnet where the field flows out is designated as the North (seeking) pole.  The field flows back in at the South pole and completes the loop inside the magnet.  If you don't have a magnet (or an electromagnet), then you don't have anything to designate as a pole.